# Does independence-friendly logic have a completeness theorem?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

It is a well-known (and frankly magical) property that first-order logic is strongly semantically complete (Gödels completeness theorem).

Independence-friendly logic is just like first-order logic but it allows quantifiers to only depend on some of the variables outside its scope.

For example: $\forall w \forall x \exists y_{\setminus{w}}  \exists z_{ \setminus x} P(w,x,y,z)$ would state that y only depends on w and z only depends on x. This is not expressible in first-order logic.

My question is: Is there an equivalent of the completeness theorem for independence-friendly logic?

Comment: I have no idea how this got a vote to close. It's a perfectly fine question; we don't demand (for example) that algebraic geometry questions all define "scheme" etc. I suspect the close voter is not familiar with IF-logic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a precise sense the answer is **no**.

In terms of expressive power, IF-logic is equivalent to existential second-order logic ESO. Now while ESO is reasonably tame in several ways (e.g. compactness and Lowenheim-Skolem), as far as *complexity* goes it's quite wild: for example, we can reduce the problem of telling whether a first-order sentence is true in $\mathbb{N}$ to the problem of telling whether a related **universal** second-order sentence is valid. Using a proof procedure for IF-logic, we could enumerate the ESO validities and so co-enumerate the USO validities, and this means that any such proof procedure must be "within one Turing jump" of computing true first-order arithmetic. In particular, this means there is no computable proof procedure for ESO (or equivalently IF).

See also Feferman, [*What kind of logic is "independence-friendly logic"?](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=d1341268f509f4fd99dc6c4ff1145c832ff1be53).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarifying Loewenheim-Skolem theorem which would have been a follow up question.
I've read that IF-logic is equivalent to $\Sigma_1^1$ wrt. to satisfiability but not validity. If I understand it correctly, it means that IF-logic can be even stronger than ESO, so it definitely isn't semantically complete.
Now I need to wrap my head around something being equivalent wrt. satisfiability  (and therefore equivalent wrt. contradiction), but somehow not equivalent wrt. to validity.

Comment: @KevinDeKeyser Remember that IF-logic doesn't have negation, so the usual connection between satisfiability and validity (via contradiction) is broken.

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense. Thanks Noah!